Flutter APK not found in the expected directory after building with flavors
I'm working on a Flutter project with multiple flavors (dev and prod). The APK builds successfully into the correct directory for the flavor, but when launching, the system looks for the APK in a different, non-flavor-specific path and fails to find it.
Here’s the error message I get:
✓ Built build/host/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk.
"build/host/outputs/apk/debug/app-dev-debug.apk" does not exist.
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.

My Setup:
build.gradle:
def flutterPluginVersion = 'managed'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // Conditional for compatibility with AGP <4.2.
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace "com.******.host"
    }

    compileSdk 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.******.host"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.******.host"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.******.host"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        profile {
            initWith debug
        }
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

buildDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "../build/host")

dependencies {
    implementation project(':flutter')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}

Command to run:
flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/dev_application.dart
flutter run --flavor prod -t lib/prod_application.dart
I also tried:
flutter run --flavor dev --debug -t lib/dev_application.dart
flutter run --flavor prod --debug -t lib/prod_application.dart
Question:
How can I ensure that the APK is found in the correct flavor-specific directory during the launch process? Is there any configuration I’m missing or any steps I need to follow to align the build output paths with the launch process?

If you go to build/host/outputs/apk/, what will you find there?

In build/host/outputs/apk/ directory there are 'dev' and 'prod' folders with 'app-dev-debug.apk' and 'app-prod-debug.apk' in them
